# Is it possible to convert Install Shield project to Advanced Setup Project in VS 2015 Community Edition?

Tags: installshield-le, advanced-installer, vs-community-edition

**Install Shield LE 2015** project (.isproj) will not work in **Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition**

Is it possible to convert that project to **Advanced Installer Project** (.aiproj)

Answer (score 0):

IS LE projects cannot be imported into Advanced Installer.

Advanced Installer can [import MSI packages](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-import-msi.html), if you have the MSI generated by our project.

You will obtain an Advanced Installer project (.aip). You can take this file and import it into your VS solution, in an Advanced Installer VS project (.aiproj), using the option add a new source file to your VS project.